# Optimize matrix arrangement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's imagine I have a Matrix $\textbf{C}$ whose construction depends on several parameters (and constraints).

I'm interested in maximizing a value $K$ calculated as:

$K=\frac{-1}{C_{1,1}^{-1}}$

where $C_{1,1}^{-1}$ is the first element of the inverse matrix.

I know that we should never calculate the inverse of a huge matrix. So i can rewrite my problem otherwise but the question will remain the same: is it possible to optimize matrix arrangement corresponding to given constraints to maximize a given value depending on the inverse matrix ? If yes, how ? Is there any theory about it ?

Comment: Hi user3473016 it seems that one of your questions is how to get $C_{1,1}$ without inverting the matrix?

Comment: $C_{1,1}^{-1}$ actually is that possible ?

Comment: I know of 2 results http://www.pardiso-project.org/download/final_paper.pdf and a numerical method.

Comment: $C_{1,1}^{-1}$ will be the $(1, 1)$-minor of $C$ divided by $\det(C)$. (Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) and maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) if you need to see the derivation.) I hope that this form will be analytical enough for you to compute partial derivatives with respect to whatever parameters you have.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chapter in Wilf's book "Mathematical Methods for Digital Computers" p 78. But it is a Monte Carlo approach so therefore it has limited accuracy.

They talk about it here:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61813/how-to-find-one-column-or-one-entry-of-the-matrix-inversion